# Known for my code

Tags: riddle, knowledge, letters

I am known for my code. If you add a letter before my last one, my first three letters are never eaten by my last five letters. What is my first letter?

Answer (score 22):

> Your first letter is H and your name is Hammurabi.

I am known for my code

> The code of Hammurabi is one of the earliest laws known

if you add a letter before my last one my first three letters are never eaten by my last five letters

> the four last letters are rabi, add another 'b' and you get a rabbi, who never would eat ham.

what is my first letter

> H